# Dell inspiron M5010 gets slow after upgrade

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, dell

I have recently updated ubuntu from 10.10 to 11.04 on my Dell inspiron M5010 laptop. The problem is that ubuntu became incredibly slow. For example during installation files were copied in few minutes but system was configuring like 1.5 hour. Also I am able to start ubuntu after isntallation but it takes up to 15 minutes to boot to desktop. All commands in terminal take a lot of time etc. I tried disabling/enabling bios options but there was no use. I guess that the new kernel may be th issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of investigation I noticed an "Disabling irq #18" error while booting. I had to disable acpi ("acpi=off") in boot options. Not it works well